# How to do conditional regex replace in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to use `-replace` statement to do the conditional replacement in PowerShell.

Below is my reproduceable example:

```
$content = @'
a&lt;a
a&gt;a
a&apos;a
a&quote;a
a&amp;a
johnson&johnson
J&J
R&D
P&AB
M&ABC
O&ABCD
B&SS-IHC
S&B
GC&E
M&G
P&D
'@
```

I want to replace all the `&` with `&amp;`, but if the string is ended with `;` then don't replace.
The result would be:

```
a&lt;a
a&gt;a
a&apos;a
a&quote;a
johnson&amp;johnson
J&amp;J
R&amp;D
P&amp;AB
M&amp;ABC
O&amp;ABCD
B&amp;SS-IHC
S&amp;B
GC&amp;E
M&amp;G
P&amp;D
```

So far I can only come up with `$modifiedContent = $content -replace '(\w)&(\w*)[^;]|$' , '$1&amp;$2'`
and I am getting nowhere. How can I add a condition correctly that will do the trick?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `-replace '\b&(?!\w+;)(?=\w)', '&amp;'`

Comment: You can match `&` not followed by any of the alternatives `&(?!lt|gt|amp|quote|apos)` https://regex101.com/r/AYlNsW/1

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```cs
\b&\b(?!\w+;)
```

Replace with `&amp;`. See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I3O0pk/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word char is required immediately to the left of the current location
- `&` - a `&` char
- `\b` - a word char is required immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?!\w+;)` - immediately to the right, there should be no 1+ word chars and a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also specify what you don't want to match as it seems you want to exclude certain special entities.

Use a negative lookahead with an alternation to assert what is at the right is not any of the listed alternatives followed by a `;` and replace with `&amp;`

```
&(?!(?:lt|gt|amp|quote|apos);)
```

**Explanation**

- `&` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:lt|gt|amp|quote|apos);` Match any of the listed followed by `;`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYDrl2/1)

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
([regex]"(\S*)(&)(?!\S*;)(\S*)").Replace($content, '$1&amp;$3')
```